# Нужно вычислить сумму из одного столбца и второго столбца и получить сумму

Tags: sql, oracle

Привет всем вот следующая информация

```
                   в соммы
 summa        summa_som       ntype_operation    course_valname       datecourse
 ----------     ------------      ---------------   ---------    -----------
    100               6900              BUY              USD         15/03/2017
    100               6990              SELL             USD         15/03/2017
    100               7400              BUY              EUR         15/03/2017
    100               7520              SELL             EUR         15/03/2017
```

Я хочу вычислить прибыль если человек купил у меня 100 долларов по курсу 69 а курс 68 то я получу прибыль 100. Беря значение покупок и продаж из другой таблицы

Table t_course

```
course_valname   datecourse buy  sell
-------------    ---------- ---- ----
USD              15/03/2017 69   69.9
EUR              15/03/2017 74   75.2
```

Запустил этот код получил следующий результат.

```
 select summa_som,
       max(case when ntype_operation = 'BUY' then summa_som
                when  ntype_operation = 'SELL' then summa_som - summa * get_rate2
(date_operation,course_valname,upper(substr(ntype_operation,1,1)))                  
                else 0
           end) as income,
       course_valname,NTYPE_OPERATION
from t_operation
WHERE DATECOURSE = TO_DATE('3/15/2017','MM/DD/YYYY')
and summa = 100
group by summa_som, course_valname,NTYPE_OPERATION;



summa_som income course_valname ntype_operation
------------------------------------------------
7392       7392       EUR          BUY
7594         0        EUR          SELL
```

Там где ноль должен быть результат сложение 7594 - 7392 =  202 в income
а где buy 7392 income по идее должно быть ноль и вовсе не отображать то что это покупка по идее мой обменник получает прибыль с того что продает по дороже. Мне вот нужно вывести разницу.

Comment: Покажите, как Вы пробовали считать эту сумму сами?

Comment: Добавил  в тему.

Comment: Вы зачем то пробуете использовать в своем примере group by и sum - означает ли это что надо получить эту прибыль не по каждой строке отдельно а суммарную в определенном разрезе. Кроме того в примере запроса вы используете колонку summa_som, которой нет в описании таблиц. И в запросе почему то нет попыток использовать курс из второй таблицы. Кстати поясните структуру таблицы курсов, там есть курсы на каждую дату, включая выходные или только даты смены курса (когда биржа работает)

Comment: Курсы в таблицу курсов я туда залил используя dbms_random.value, я не знаю почему там sum ) Добавлю в тему еще пример что я хочу в результате получить

Comment: К запросу надо подходить последовательно, сначала включаем в запрос все необходимые таблицы и добиваемся что бы в каждой строке начальных данных были все необходимые для расчетов данные. потом начинаем считать нужные величины и после этого уже группируем. Вот для первой фазы надо склеить таблицу данных с курсами и тут надо знать на все ли даты гарантированно есть курс и решить что делать если курса на нужную дату нет, если такое возможно

Comment: А что касается формулы расчета ... мне кажется надо умножить summa на курс после чего вычесть summa_som и умножить на 1 или -1 в зависимости от того продажа это или покупка. потому что прибыль (или убыток) может быть как на покупке так и на продаже, только знак должен быть разным для прибыли в зависимости от направления обмена. И вы уверены, что хотите видеть только положительный доход и считать убытки равными 0

Comment: даты все есть до 2025 года  ) щас попробую как вы сказали спасибо что то не хочет он выдавать остаток так как надо, все время дает 0 результат

Comment: Я в вашем запросе так и не увидел использования таблицы курсов. базовый запрос, раз даты все есть, будет какой то такой `select * from t_operation o,  t_course c where c.datecourse=o.datecourse and c.course_valname=t.course_valname`